# convert decimal as well as character to hex and stored it into unsigned array and send it to bluetooth

Tags: java, bluetooth

sorry guys actually i was confused thats why i cant ask properly now my question is,

i want to convert decimal as well as character into hex and store this data into unsigned/long array and want to send this array to bluetooth..

for ex:
i have data like **"Q @ 716(decimal)"**

after converting it should like **"51 40 2CC"**

now i want to add this data into array a, which is unsigned or long, 
 **a[0] = 51, a[1] = 40, a[2]=02, a[3] = CC**

how can i do this.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know exactly problem but it looks like you can replace HEX to Base64 and use Base64 class from org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: from the string i want data like  Q(51)@(40)53222(cfe6)*(2A)0*(2A) and so on.first 4 character gave me Q@ next i want to do hex conversion for cfe6.then agian i got char 2A which give *.

Comment: basically i want to separate hex value and special characters from the string.

Comment: cfe6 is no valid hex value. a hex value consists of 2 characters and not 4. therefore the output shall be `Q@Ïæ* 3%*³`. Some of these characters wont be displayed in eclipse just like here. what i posted is missing some values which aren't displayed properly, because they are special characters

Comment: cfe6 is hex value of no 53222.  @XtremeBaumer

Comment: but that is nothing you convert to a ascii value. if you want to convert hex to ascii, you always take only 2 characters. here you can look up the corresponding hex-value and character http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm

Comment: no  i want to convert it (cfe6) into decimal.

Comment: The number of hex characters are not even `51 40 cf e6 2A 02 A0 33 25 2A 16 11 13 B3 B`

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. `(char)` casting converts an integer-typed value of a UTF-16 code unit to a Java text datatype. So, you have to have a UTF-16 code unit value to use it sensibly. There _could_ be a chain of reasoning that you have a `byte` or `byte[]` that holds code units from a different encoding (you've mentioned ASCII) and that the values are the same in the two encodings but you could make that explicit in the code. Going further, you could make it clearer by getting a `byte[]` in the source encoding and converting it to `String`. In short, `char` != `byte` (or `int`).

Comment: hey buddy sorry actually  i was confused so cant ask properly,actually i want to convert decimal value and special character into hex. and store it into unsigned array  or (any suggession from u) and want to send this array to Bluetooth. i have done converting part, i take hex equivalent for special character (ex for ; = 3B, *=2A) now i want to store it in array,i dont want send this as  string to bluetooth i want to send it as hex to bluetooth.. @Tom Blodget, XtremeBaumer